# Gemfile.lock keeps changing when running 'rake spec'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler

I have a rails 3 project with Bundler and Capistrano. Everything is working properly, but when i run `rake spec` the Gemfile.lock changes. The change is that two lines are swapped. Here's the diff:

```
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -44,8 +44,8 @@ GEM
     capistrano (2.5.20)
       highline
       highline
-      net-scp
       net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
+      net-scp
       net-sftp
       net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
       net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
```

When i run `rake spec` a second time the lines are swapped again and the change is undone. I am very much puzzled by this behavior. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the capistrano gemspec declaring dependencies twice. See [this ticket](https://capistrano.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8716/tickets/187-gemspec-for-2520-declares-dependencies-twice).

Comment: Happy to see it's a bug :) Thanks for the quick answer!